# postgreSQL default collation (case insensitive)

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 12 and I would like to create a schema with insensitive collation. I read about Nondeterministic Collations here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html

When I create a new Database I always get the collation German_Germany.1252. This is not listed in pg_collations. I tried to create a new collation and use it like this

```
CREATE COLLATION german FROM "de_DE";
create database test2 LC_COLLATE german;
```

but the new database is also created with German_Germany.1252. I read that PostgreSQL use the collations provided by the operating system. I am running on windows and by executing the command line systeminfo, I get

```
System Locale en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale de;German (Germany)
```

So I assume that German_Germany.1252 comes from my windows, is there a way to change it to be nondeterministic or case-insensitive?

In generla is there any way to set a case-insensitive collation in PostgreSQL?

Comment: is there a good cause wh not using utf8mb4 with it  collations.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/273394/176905), but the answer isn't upvoted, so I cannot mark it as a duplicate. You can define a case insensitive collation if you have ICU support configured, but you cannot use that collation as the default collation of a database.